# Multiple API Calls with Promise.all

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch-api, react-state

I'm trying to get different data from different APIs. I don't have any problem when getting one and updating state, but I can't figure out how can I update two different state with `Promise.all()`.

How can I make this code work?

```
const [stats, setStats] = useState(null);
const [info, setInfo] = useState(null);

 React.useEffect(()=>{
Promise.all([
  fetch('https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collection/nickelodeon-rugrats-heyarnold-eth/stats'),
  fetch('https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/asset_contract/0x223E16c52436CAb2cA9FE37087C79986a288FFFA')])
  .then(res =>Promise.all(res.map(r=> r.json())))
  .then((stats) => {
    setStats(stats);
  })
  .then((info) => {
    setInfo(info);
  })
  .then(data =>  console.log(data)).catch(error => console.log(error));
},[])
```

Comment: Can you give more info on what you're trying to achieve? Is it so you can update stats & info at the same time rather than the user seeing them load at diff times? If so, there's better ways of achieving this -- will answer if this is what you need. You only need `Promise.all` if you need to know, for some reason, when both requests are finished. If you dont, you just make 2 fetch calls with their own promise chain in the effect, totally seperate with no `Promise.all` needed

Comment: Why do you even want to wait for both requests before setting the two states? If you have two independent states, you shouldn't need `Promise.all` - and if you always want both values together, you should use a single state (holding an array) instead.

Answer (score 4):

The `Promise.all`s are resolving to an array of resolve values, so the later `.then`s should use that array - the two URLs being fetched doesn't result in two separate `.then`s, it only results in a single Promise that you need to extract two properties out of.

You can also make the code simpler and DRYer by starting with an array of the two URLs and mapping over them.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const urls = ['https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collection/nickelodeon-rugrats-heyarnold-eth/stats', 'https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/asset_contract/0x223E16c52436CAb2cA9FE37087C79986a288FFFA'];
    Promise.all(urls.map(url => fetch(url).then(r => r.json())))
        .then(([stats, info]) => {
            setStats(stats);
            setInfo(info);
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
}, []);
```

Comment: thank you for response. but i can get error when render 

`<p>{stats.stats.total_supply}</p>`

Cannot read properties of null (reading 'stats')

Comment: The state variable isn't populated on pageload - it takes some milliseconds for the API call to finish and for the component to re-render. Only try to access the nested properties of state if it exists in the first place, eg `<p>{stats?.stats?.total_supply}</p>` or `{ stats && <p>{stats.stats.total_supply}</p> }`

Comment: you are right. sorry i am a newbie. i guess i need to look back some of the fundamentals.