# How to Fetch Data from Multiple API in one function?

Tags: javascript, fetch, array.prototype.map

Here is my codes:

```
const ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

const fD= () => {
        const fP = ids?.map(async (id) => {
            const { data } = await axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}/comments`);
            return data;
        })
       return fP;
    };
    console.log(fD());
```

my following codes is not working to fetch data and get data same as i expected.

I am trying to fetch 10 API in one time to get the information and get them in one array. somethings like this: (suppose i fetch only id's from all API)

Expected Output:

```
[[{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}],[{6},{7},{8},{9},{10}],[{11},{12},{13},{14},{15}],[{16},{17},{18},{19},{20}],[{21},{22},{23},{24},{25}],[{26},{27},{28},{29},{30}],[{31},{32},{33},{34},{35}],[{36},{37},{38},{39},{40}],[{41},{42},{43},{44},{45}],]{46},{47},{48},{49},{50}]]
```

How Can i fetch multiple API in one time and get all the data in array?
Anyone can help me to fetch multiple API in one time and fetch those data same as i Expect.
Thankyou for Your  helping in advance!

Comment: `fD` should be returning an Array of Promises - can you confirm that? so `fD().then(console.log)` should output the data you are expecting

Comment: If you log `fP` in console you will probably see a bunch of pending promises. Contrary to what we may usually think, the async operations on every iteration of the `map` method are not awaited just like that. You should use `Promise.all` if you need all the promises to resolve in parallel or `for...of` loop if you want to make the async calls sequentially.

Comment: Maybe Im missing something but the expected output is invalid syntax? You try to assign number to a object without the property/value and I dont know why people in this thread is entertaining your idea, it will not work.

Answer (score -1):

I think `promise.all()` will solve your problem. It takes an array of promises as input and returns a single promise that resolves to an array of results of input promises.

Helpful links:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

[Multiple API Calls with Promise.all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73092249/multiple-api-calls-with-promise-all)